# Delete data with foreign key in SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server

I'm going to delete data in an SQL Server table (parent) which has a relationship with another table (child).
I tried the basic Delete query. But it isn't working (and I know it won't).

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE ...
```

It returned following error

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint ...

I need to keep the table's schema. I know that I just need to add some words in the query, I've ever done this before, but I just couldn't recall it.

Answer (score 63):

You can disable and re-enable the foreign key constraints before and after deleting:

```
alter table MyOtherTable nocheck constraint all
delete from MyTable
alter table MyOtherTable check constraint all
```

Comment: If you disable then re-enable the constraints, won't the re-enable fail due to the broken `foreign key` references?

Comment: No, it only checks the constraint when you write new values to a field - it doesn't rescan the whole table when you put the check back in.

Comment: Well. This means that all the data in the child table will remain there. I'm about to delete 2k rows, and I think it will be bulky if I keep the data in the child table. I think I'll just do it manually. Thx anyway for the replies guys. You deserve +1 :)

Comment: this seems a little "kludge-y" but in my particular case, I'm glad to have found this and I'm using it.

Answer (score 54):

You need to manually delete the children.  the `<condition>` is the same for both queries.

```
DELETE FROM child
FROM cTable AS child
INNER JOIN table AS parent ON child.ParentId = parent.ParentId
WHERE <condition>;

DELETE FROM parent
FROM table AS parent
WHERE <condition>;
```

Comment: Can these two DELETEs be combined in a way that I only have to write the <condition> part once?

Comment: I don't believe so @ThomasTempelmann.  If you want to only write the condition once, you'd have to turn on cascade deletes instead of manually dealing with each table.  Alastair Maw's answer here references this option as well.

Answer (score 24):

If you wish the delete to be automatic, you need to change your schema so that the foreign key constraint is `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

For more information, see the [MSDN page on Cascading Referential Integrity Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933119%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

ETA (after clarification from the poster): If you can't update the schema, you have to manually DELETE the affected child records first.

Comment: ah. I missed to tell that part in my post, I have to get it worked without changing the schema. it's possible right ?

Comment: No, it's not possible with some magic query OPTION or whatever. You need to manually do the deletes.

Answer (score 11):

> here you are adding the foreign key for your "Child" table

```
ALTER TABLE child
ADD FOREIGN KEY (P_Id)
REFERENCES parent(P_Id) 
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

> After that if you make a DELETE query on "Parent" table like this

```
DELETE FROM parent WHERE .....
```

> since the child has a reference to parent with DELETE CASCADE, the "Child" rows also will be deleted! along with the "parent".

Comment: Still not working. Here is my error `ERROR:  update or delete on table "question" violates foreign key constraint "answer_question_id_fkey" on table "answer"
DETAIL:  Key (question_id)=(14) is still referenced from table "answer".
SQL state: 23503`

Answer (score 3):

So, you need to `DELETE` related rows from conflicted tables or more logical to `UPDATE` their `FOREIGN KEY` column to reference other `PRIMARY KEY`'s from the parent table.

Also, you may want to read this article [Don’t Delete – Just Don’t](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/09/01/dont-delete-just-dont/)

Answer (score 3):

To delete data from the tables having relationship of parent_child,
First you have to delete the data from the child table by mentioning join then simply delete the data from the parent table, example is given below:

```
DELETE ChildTable
FROM ChildTable inner join ChildTable on PParentTable.ID=ChildTable.ParentTableID
WHERE <WHERE CONDITION> 


DELETE  ParentTable
WHERE <WHERE CONDITION>
```

Comment: This is the best answer if you're not cascading delete.  Cursors perform horribly and removing the constraints to delete could leave orphaned rows in other tables.

Answer (score 1):

Usefull script which you can delete all data in all tables of a database ,
replace tt with you databse name :

```
declare @tablename nvarchar(100)
declare c1 cursor for
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_CATALOG='tt' AND TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'

open  c1
fetch next from c1 into @tablename

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin
    print @t1
        exec('alter table ' + @tablename + ' nocheck constraint all')
        exec('delete from ' + @tablename)
        exec ('alter table ' + @tablename + ' check constraint all')
        fetch next from c1 into @tablename
    end
close c1
DEALLOCATE c1
```

Answer (score 0):

I used triggers to delete entries referencing the primary key. Not sure if you can do that if you can't change the schema, but here is an example in SQLite:

```
CREATE TRIGGER remove_parent
  BEFORE DELETE ON parent
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM
    child
  WHERE
    child.id = OLD.id;
END;
```

This way every time you delete a parent entry, child entries will also be deleted first.

Answer (score 0):

### Simple solution:

Delete an sub-table Using MySQL control panel:

[image]

Comment: Tagged sql-server, not MySql

Answer (score -1):

```sql
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
DELETE FROM yourtable;
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Comment: This answer causes datainconsistency within you database. Use it only if you know what you're doing.

Comment: Tagged sql-server, not MySQL

Answer (score -2):

Set the FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS before and after your delete SQL statements.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
DELETE FROM table WHERE ...
DELETE FROM table WHERE ...
DELETE FROM table WHERE ...
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Source: https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/mysql/drop-mysql-tables-in-any-order-foreign-keys.

Comment: The question is about SQL Server, not MySQL

Comment: This answer causes datainconsistency within you database. Use it only if you know what you're doing. It would be nice, if @Shaunlgs would've explained more.