# How to delete from 2 tables using join query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join, using

[Table relationships][1]

[image: table **Student**]

[image: table **Student_Grade**]

Here are the screenshots of my database.

I want to delete all the data from the `Student` table using the `Student_grade` table where `Grade='FAIL'`.

ALL the information of the failed students should be deleted from the database.

```
Delete from Student
where Student_ID IN (Select Student_ID 
                     from Student_Grade 
                     where Grade = 'FAIL');
```

Tried this but it's not working. I think data should be deleted from both tables at once because when it deletes from one `Student` table there is no references for FK in `student_grade` table.

Please can anyone provide the SQL Server query to do this?

Comment: Explore ON DELETE CASCADE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260688/how-do-i-use-cascade-delete-with-sql-server

Comment: put TOP 1 in your select and change IN to =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually like Squirrel's temp approach (+1).  It allows for a more complex selection criteria.

That said, if #temp tables are "off-the-table", you can do the following:

```
Delete A
 From  Student A
 Join  Student_grade B on (A.Student_ID=B.Student_ID)
 Where B.Grade='Fail';

Delete From Student_grade Where Grade='Fail';
```

Answer (score 2):

you can't delete from 2 tables in one go.

Keep the list of studend_id to be deleted in a temp table and then use that to join to the actual table and delete one at a time.

```
-- put the list of Fail students in temp table #Fail
Select Student_ID INTO #Fail from Student_Grade where Grade='FAIL'

-- delete from grade table
DELETE g FROM #Fail f INNER JOIN Student_Grade g ON f.Student_ID = g.Student_ID

-- delete from student table
DELETE s FROM #Fail f INNER JOIN Student s ON f.Student_ID = s.Student_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two way doing it.

first way,use transaction when using more than one DML

```
begin try
begin tran

-- Child table
Delete From Student_grade Where Grade='Fail';

-- Parent table
Delete A
 From  Student A
 Join  Student_grade B on (A.Student_ID=B.Student_ID)
 Where B.Grade='Fail';



commit TRAN
end try
begin catch
if (@@Trancount>0)
rollback
end catch
```

Another way is to use

> Delete Cascade

,if you want to delete parent table straight away.
[Delete data with foreign key in SQL Server table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251146/delete-data-with-foreign-key-in-sql-server-table)