# How to delete a row which is having a Foreign Key?

Tags: sql-server, database

Here i am having 3 tables named t1, t2, t3

```
id    dept_name

201      CSE
202      ECE
203      IT
204      MECH
205      EEE
   **T1**

id   dept_per

201     50
202     60
203     70
204     80
205     80
  **T2**

id     dept_rank
 201     2
 202     4
 203     1
 204     5
 205     3
   **T3**
```

Here Id is the primary key and the T2 & T3 have its foriegn Key.Now i want to delete a single row in the table T3 but it is not allowing me to delete that row because of the foreign key. How can i delete that row without removing a foreign key.

Comment: Hint: `nocheck constraint all`

Comment: If you deleting a row that has a relationship. You need to remove the relationship before you delete the primary key.

Comment: @Sami So using this nocheck constraint all we can disable  all constraints in the database  right?

Comment: @JeroldJoel Yup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete data with foreign key in SQL Server table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251146/delete-data-with-foreign-key-in-sql-server-table)

Comment: @Sami Just check the answer i posted below is correct right??

Comment: @JeroldJoel If your answer is right, then your question is duplicate :)

Comment: @Sami Just now i got that answer from the old post

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer from the old post just now

> [How can foreign key constraints be temporarily disabled using T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159038/how-can-foreign-key-constraints-be-temporarily-disabled-using-t-sql)

If you want to disable all constraints in the database just run this code:

```
-- disable all constraints
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"
```

To
switch them back on, run: (the print is optional of course and it is
just listing the tables)

```
-- enable all constraints
exec sp_MSforeachtable @command1="print '?'", 
     @command2="ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all"
```